# ¿por que cuando pongo una funcion como valor de array me retorna sintaxis de funcion y no su valor?

Tags: javascript, array, function

```
var A = [ 'dog', 'cat', function () { return 2 * 2 } ] ;

document.body.innerHTML = A[2]
```

Retorna esto: **function () { return 2 * 2 }**
Obviamente yo quiero que me retorne **4**, no la sintaxis de una funcion
¿o es que no se puede meter una funcion en un array?

Comment: tienes que hacer algo con esa función? , sería una de las preguntas que te haría, pero la otra por qué no simplemente colocas el 4 ?, y otra cosa las funciones nunca las he visto dentro de los array. Creo que te hace falta explicar más para que quieres hacer eso o que es lo que espera y esas cosas .Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te devuelve lo que le pides. En el array está la función y te devuelve la función. Si lo que quieres es el resultado de ejecutar la función, tienes que pedirlo.

```
document.body.innerHTML = A[2]();
```

Si `A[2]` es una función, entonces `A[2]()` es una llamada a dicha función y obtendrás el valor devuelto por la misma.

Comment: Funcionó... No sé si ésta será la forma correcta de hacerlo -sospecho que sí porque cuando llamas métodos de objetos es igual- pero la cosa es que funciona. Voy a averiguar si los arrays soportan funciones adentro, porque podría ser que funcione pero que no sea correcto. Bueno gracias, y gracias al otro señor también por contestar.

Comment: @lalo2019, Date cuenta que `function algo(){...}` puede escribirse como  `var algo = function(){...}` y en ambos casos invocas a la función con `algo()`. Tu código se encuentra en el segundo caso.

Comment: tienes razón. por lógica, si se pueden crear funciones como variables, un array -que es una variable con múltiples valores- también debe poder soportar funciones...supongo que todo lo de la variable se aplica al array, que repito, es un tipo de variable